# how to create milky overlay in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I'm working with `Vue 3` and `Bootstrap 5`.

I have a `button` and two `inputs`. When I click the `button` I want to have a `"milky" overlay` like following:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Code to work with:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @click="overlayMilky()">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-12">
      <span>Input 2</span>
      <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <span>Input 3</span>
      <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      overlayMilky() {
        //set overlay to milky 
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: lower the opacity would do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to surround the inputs with a `container` element and give this element `position: relative` and add to it a child which will be the `overlay`, this should have `position: absolute` to be absolute to the `container` element, also should have `width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;` to take the full size of the container element and then conditionally with `v-if` you can `show/hide` it with a `state`

```
<div v-if="showOverlay" class="overlay"></div>
```

```
  methods: {
    overlayMilky() {
      this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay;
      //set overlay to milky
    },
  },
```

This is a full example of code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="btn btn-dark" @click="overlayMilky()">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div v-if="showOverlay" class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-12">
          <span>Input 2</span>
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <span>Input 3</span>
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showOverlay: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    overlayMilky() {
      this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay;
      //set overlay to milky
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
</style>
```

[image: Edit vue3-bootstrap (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `data` field that will describe the "milky" overlay state.
So all you need to do in the `overlayMilky` method is to set `this.milkyOverlay = true`.
Then use this `milkyOverlay` property to add the milky css class or show milky div on top.